# Generate numbers between min_value and max_value oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have two methods for solution, but both are high inefficient to work with value of the order 10<sup>8</sup> and greater.

**Method 1**

```
 select 100 + rownum - 1 from dual connect by level <= (200 - 100 + 1)
```

**Method 2**

```
select rownum + 100 - 1
from (select 1 from dual group by cube(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
where rownum < (200 - 100 + 1)
```

but first method fails when the max value is 100,000,000 and second method takes lot of time to process.

please suggest an efficient method,
I could think of sequences but I suppose the time cost will be higher.

**update**

*Error in First method*

> ORA-30009: Not enough memory for CONNECT BY operation

Comment: I don't think there is an *efficient* way to create 100,000,000 rows.  That seems like an unusual requirement.

Comment: can you atleast, let us know how to resolve first error? please check the update.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely an unusual requirement. Funny though, I too had to produce a list of the numbers up to 100,000,000 only recently. I used a recursive cte query and it was slow. It was 20 times as fast to simply retrieve `rownum` from a large enough table instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For that many rows a pipelined function would probably the best solution:

```
create or replace TYPE t_numbers IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

create or replace function generate_series(p_min integer, p_max integer)
  return t_numbers pipelined
as  
begin
  for i in p_min..p_max loop
    pipe row (i);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

A simple:

```
select count(*)
from table(generate_series(1,100000000));
```

This takes about 30 seconds on my laptop

Comment: You are right; I just tried it and it's blazingly fast.

Answer (score 2):

Some other options:

**Option 1 - Generate a collection**:

```
CREATE TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER(10,0);
/

CREATE FUNCTION list_between(
  min_value NUMBER,
  max_value NUMBER
) RETURN intlist DETERMINISTIC
AS
  o_lst intlist := intlist();
BEGIN
  IF ( min_value <= max_value ) THEN
    o_lst.EXTEND( max_value - min_value + 1 );
    FOR i IN 0 .. max_value - min_value LOOP
      o_lst( i ) := i + min_value;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
  RETURN o_lst;
END;
/

SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
FROM   TABLE( list_between( 123456789, 987654321 ) );
```

**Option 2 - Use a recursive sub-query factoring clause**:

```
WITH sqfc ( min_value, max_value ) AS (
  SELECT 123456789, 987654321 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT min_value + 1, max_value
  FROM   sqfc
  WHERE  min_value < max_value
)
SELECT min_value AS value
FROM   sqfc;
```

**Option 3 - Use a pipelined function**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pipelined_list_between (
  min_value NUMBER,
  max_value NUMBER
) RETURN intlist DETERMINISTIC PIPELINED
AS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN min_value .. max_value LOOP
    PIPE ROW ( i );
  END LOOP;
END;
/

SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
FROM   TABLE( pipelined_list_between( 123456789, 987654321 ) );
```

Comment: Option 1 produces a memory error on my machine. Option 2 is slow. Option 3 which you added in your last edit is fast and well-written.

Answer (score 0):

Variation of your first method.

```
select  rownum + min_val
    from (
               select rownum rn
               from
                       (select rownum rn from dual connect by level <= 1000) t1,
                       (select rownum rn from dual connect by level <= 1000) t2,
                       (select rownum rn from dual connect by level <= 1000) t3
               where rownum <= max_val- min_val +1
       )
```